# Magento: pass data between observers

Tags: php, magento

I have the following problem:

I use the observer "controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_saveBilling" for getting the value of a custom dropdown in the billing section, with this dropdown the user can select the customer group, but only if he is creating an account in the checkout phase.

Now I want to set the customer group selected by the user with the "sales_order_place_after" observer, but I can't understand how to pass the group_custom_id value from the first observer to the second one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Register both observers as singleton, using

   ```
   <type>singleton</type>
   ```

   in your `config.xml` (or leaving it out, because it's the default type)
2. Store your data as property within the observer class itself

   ```
   class My_Module_Model_Observer
   {
       protected $_myDropdownValue;

       public function onSaveBilling(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
       {
           // ...
           $this->_myDropdownValue = ...;
       }

       public function onPlaceOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
       {
           //access value with $this->_myDropdownValue;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Remember to [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).  Store the value in a variable, perhaps in your observer class since observers are normally singletons and singletons don't go away until the page is served.